# Keep rectangle B aligned on top of Rectangle A even when Rectangle A's anchor changes

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have a project where I need to create a rectangle and then another rectangle that has to be placed on top of the first rectangle.

Rectangle `A` is a `PIXI.Graphics` object so the user of the application can change various properties such as the anchor of the rectangle.

Rectangle `B` is not a PIXI object but just a rectangle that has to overlay on top.

This makes it hard to keep Rectangle B aligned to Rectangle `A` when rectangle A's anchor is changed, and therefore its position on the game is changed.

To demonstrate I have created a snippet with both rectangles being graphics objects so that the Rectangle `B` can be seen, but in real application Rectangle, `B` is not a `PIXI.Graphics` object.

```js
const app = new PIXI.Application(800, 600, { backgroundColor: 0x1099bb });
document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const rectangleA = new PIXI.Graphics();
rectangleA.beginFill(0x000000);
rectangleA.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
rectangleA.position.set(100, 100);
rectangleA.endFill();

const rectangleB = new PIXI.Graphics();
rectangleB.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
rectangleB.alpha = 0.5;
rectangleB.drawRect(rectangleA.x, rectangleA.y, 100, 100);
rectangleB.endFill();

app.stage.addChild(rectangleA);
app.stage.addChild(rectangleB);
```

```html
<script src="https://pixijs.download/v5.0.0-alpha.3/pixi.min.js"></script>
```

I have figured out that if I change Rectangle A's anchor to `(0.5, 0.5)` then Rectangle B's position can be adjust to: `(rectangleA.x - (rectangleA.width / 2), rectangleA.y - (rectangleA.height / 2))`

And If I change the anchor to `(0.25, 0.25)` then Rectangle B's position can be adjusted to: `(rectangleA.x - (rectangleA.width / 4), rectangleA.y - (rectangleA.height / 4))`

So it seems the correlation is that when I half Rectangle A's anchor, I double what I divide by in Rectangle B's position.

The problem is that the anchor can be any value between 0 to 1 and is chosen by the user so I can't rely on the pattern.

Is there an algorithm or formula to represent the above correlation and keep Rectangle B's position the same as Rectangle A's even when Rectangle A's anchor is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x / 2 == x * (1 / 2) == 2 * 0.5
x / 4 == x * (1 / 4) == x * 0.25
-or-
x / y == x * (1 / y)
```

This means your formula is:

```
rectangleB.x = rectangleA.x - (rectangleA.width * rectangleA.anchor.x);
rectangleB.y = rectangleA.y - (rectangleA.height * rectangleA.anchor.y);
```

Or, if you want to see the `/ 2` and `/ 4` you've tried:

```
rectangleB.x = rectangleA.x - (rectangleA.width / (1 / rectangleA.anchor.x));
rectangleB.y = rectangleA.y - (rectangleA.height / (1 / rectangleA.anchor.y));
```